# How to Create Search View on Android Fragment Toolbar?

Tags: android, fragment, searchview

I am working on a app in which it recieves the data from json and i wnat to apply searchview in for filter purpose i have implement the onQueryTextChange and onQueryTextSubmit method .the problem i am facing that when i search it does not show any thing i have no idea whats happning anyone help me please how to implement searchview.
this is my fragment class

```
public class Restaurant extends Fragment{

RecyclerView restaurant_recycler;
RestaurantsAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog sweetProgressDialog;
SessionManager sessionManager;
List<Restaurant_model> itemrestaurants;
List<String> mAllValues;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_restaurant, container, false);

    restaurant_recycler = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_restaurant);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    itemrestaurants = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new RestaurantsAdapter(getContext(), itemrestaurants);
    restaurant_recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    restaurant_recycler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    restaurant_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    sweetProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(getContext());

    show_restaurants();
    return v;
}

private void show_restaurants() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
//        sweetProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsFeed.this, "Loading Postss", "Please Wait...",false,false);

    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_show_restaurants, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (sweetProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (response.isEmpty() || response == null || response.equals("0")) {
                sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Loading Restaurants, check your connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                //sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("tag", "response " + response);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)

                {
                    JSONObject thisOBj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                    itemrestaurants.add(new Restaurant_model(thisOBj.getString("id"), thisOBj.getString("name"),
                            thisOBj.getString("address"),
                            thisOBj.getString("image")));

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                if (sweetProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("myTag", error.toString());
                    if (sweetProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {



    myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    ));
    myReq.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.add(myReq);
    sweetProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    sweetProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Restaurants...");
    sweetProgressDialog.show();
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = null;
    if (mSearchMenuItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                String result = query;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText = newText.toLowerCase();
                List<Restaurant_model> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Restaurant_model row : itemrestaurants) {
                    if (row.getRestaurant_name().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase()) || row.getRestaurant_address().contains(newText)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                    adapter.setFilter(itemrestaurants);

                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code Needs Some Repair

***`Function For Filtering:-`***

```
 private List<Restaurant_model> filtered(String search_query) {
       List<Restaurant_model> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
       for (Restaurant_model row : itemrestaurants) {
            Boolean contains =row.getRestaurant_name().toLowerCase().contains(search_query.toLowerCase()) || row.getRestaurant_address().contains(search_query)
            if (contains) {
                filteredModelList.add(row);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```

***`Function Implementation:-`***

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            newText = newText.toLowerCase();

            List<Restaurant_model> filteredList = filtered(newText);

                adapter.setFilter(filteredList);

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: khair Mubarak sir

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            newText = newText.toLowerCase();

            List<Restaurant_model> filteredList = filter(itemrestaurants, newText);

                adapter.setFilter(itemrestaurants);

            }
            return true;
        }
```

add following Method

```
private List<Restaurant_model> filter(List<Restaurant_model> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();final List<Restaurant_model> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (HomeFeedItem model : models) {
        final String text = model.getTitle().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

Try this hope it is working

Comment: well nothing is happening